# i am getting the wrong output to a problem of finding the equillibrium point in a array

Tags: c++, arrays

Given an array A of n positive numbers. The task is to find the first Equilibrium Point in an array.
Equilibrium Point in an array is a position such that the sum of elements before it is equal to the sum of elements after it.

Note: Retun the index of Equilibrium point. (1-based index)

this is what i tried

```cpp
    //{ Driver Code Starts
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    // } Driver Code Ends
    class Solution{
    public:
    // Function to find equilibrium point in the array.
    // a: input array
    // n: size of array
     int equilibriumPoint(long long a[], int n) 
    
        // Your code here
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        sum=sum+a[i];
        
        int tempsum=0;

        for(int i=n;i>=1;--i)
        { 
            sum=sum-a[i];
            tempsum=tempsum+a[i];
            if(tempsum==sum+a[i])
            return{i};
        }
        
        return{-1};
    }
};
```

my output was -1;

Comment: Edit your tags with your language. Looks like C or C++

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is that array indices start at 0, but your loops start at 1. So you're missing the first value in the array.

Comment: What array did you try this on when you got result -1?

Comment: Please provide sample input, expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 2):

You have some syntactic and semantic bugs in your code. For example wongly set braces, wrongly used indices, wrong sequence of statements and so on. Also, your variable names indicate somehow, that you do not understand the underlying algorithm.

And since you have these problems, your function will return -1. This indicates, no value found.

The solution is simple.

You have obviously the "equilibrium Point", which is called "pivot" in normal case, and, as per the requirement, the sum of the values to the left and the sum of the values to the right, shall be the same. So, you have something like a "leftSum" and a "rightSum".

- Step 1: In the beginning, for index 0, the right sum is the sum of all values. The left sum is 0
- Step 2. For index 1, the right sum, is the previously calculated complete sum minus the value at index 0. The left sum is 0 + value at index 0.
- Step 3. For index 2, the right sum, is the previously calculated complete sum minus the value at index 0 minus the value at index 1. The left sum is 0 + value at index 0 + value at index 1.
- Step 4. For index 3, the right sum, is the previously calculated complete sum minus the value at index 0 minus the value at index 1 minus the value at index 2. The left sum is 0 + value at index 0 + value at index 1 + value at index 2.

And so on and so on.

Then you just need to compare the left with the right sum. After doing the subtraction and before doing the addition.

The result would be:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Solution{
public:
    // Function to find equilibrium point in the array.
    // a: input array
    // n: size of array
    int equilibriumPoint(long long a[], int n) {
    
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
            sum=sum+a[i];
        
        int tempsum=0;

        for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        { 
            sum=sum-a[i];
            if(tempsum==sum)
                return i+1;
                
            tempsum=tempsum+a[i];
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
int main() {
    long long a[]={1,1,5,1,1};
    
    Solution s;
    std::cout << s.equilibriumPoint(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])) << '\n';
}
```

With renaming the variables a little bit, you would write:

```
  //{ Driver Code Starts
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    // } Driver Code Ends
class Solution{
public:
    // Function to find equilibrium point in the array.
    // a: input array
    // n: size of array
     int equilibriumPoint(long long a[], int n) {
    
        int rightSum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
            rightSum=rightSum+a[i];
        
        int leftSum=0;

        for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        { 
            rightSum=rightSum-a[i];
            if(leftSum==rightSum)
                return i+1;
                
            leftSum=leftSum+a[i];
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
int main() {
    long long a[]={1,1,5,1,1};
    
    Solution s;
    std::cout << s.equilibriumPoint(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])) << '\n';
}
```